# Joining of two query results results in parenthesis missing error

Tags: oracle

I tried to look for the answer on similar questions, but none of them is working.

I have two queries, and want to join the results of both. It's about the total number of runs for a certain test case in ALM.

I am getting an error about missing parenthesis but they seem to be balanced.

```
SELECT "Test Naam1", "Execution Status", "Test Case ID", "Totaal2", "Test Naam2", "Totaal1"
FROM
(
(SELECT
TS_NAME as "Test Naam",
RN_STATUS AS "Execution Status",
RN_TESTCYCL_ID AS "Test Case ID" ,
COUNT(*)  as "Totaal2"
FROM
RUN, TEST
where
RN_TESTCYCL_ID IN (8492,8493,8494,8495,8496,8497,8498,8499,8500,8502)

AND RN_TEST_ID = TS_TEST_ID
AND RN_EXECUTION_DATE  > to_date('2019/07/09 00:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')    /*calculate only after 8th of july (stable tests) */
group by
RN_STATUS,
RN_TESTCYCL_ID
  ,RN_TEST_ID
  ,TS_NAME
  ,TEST.TS_TEST_ID
  ORDER BY ts_NAME)as t1

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT
TS_NAME as "Test Naam2",
RN_TESTCYCL_ID AS "Test Case ID" ,
COUNT(*)  as "Totaal1"
FROM
RUN, TEST
where
RN_TESTCYCL_ID IN (8492,8493,8494,8495,8496,8497,8498,8499,8500,8502)

AND RN_TEST_ID = TS_TEST_ID
AND RN_EXECUTION_DATE  > to_date('2019/07/09 00:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')    /*calculate only after 8th of july (stable tests) */
group by

RN_TESTCYCL_ID
  ,RN_TEST_ID
  ,TS_NAME
  ,TEST.TS_TEST_ID
  ORDER BY ts_NAME)as t2

)
where    "Test Naam1" = "Test Naam2"
```

I would like to have as a result a table that has for every test case run per status the number of results (example test1, 12 passed, 10 failed, 5 not completed (query1) and from query2 the total runs for that particular test1 27 total runs (at the end I want to know percentages of passed runs

Comment: Third line and fourth line both start with (

Comment: You are mixing ANSI and Oracle syntaxes, which is not a good idea; you'd better completely switch to ANSI join syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues which are resolved with inline comments as following:

```
SELECT
    "Test Naam1",
    "Execution Status",
    "Test Case ID",
    "Totaal2",
    "Test Naam2",
    "Totaal1"
FROM
( (
    SELECT
        TS_NAME          AS "Test Naam",
        RN_STATUS        AS "Execution Status",
        RN_TESTCYCL_ID   AS "Test Case ID",
        COUNT(*) AS "Totaal2"
    FROM
        RUN,
        TEST
    WHERE
        RN_TESTCYCL_ID IN (
            8492,
            8493,
            8494,
            8495,
            8496,
            8497,
            8498,
            8499,
            8500,
            8502
        )
        AND RN_TEST_ID = TS_TEST_ID
        AND RN_EXECUTION_DATE > TO_DATE('2019/07/09 00:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')    /*calculate only after 8th of july (stable tests) */
    GROUP BY
        RN_STATUS,
        RN_TESTCYCL_ID,
        RN_TEST_ID,
        TS_NAME,
        TEST.TS_TEST_ID
    ORDER BY
        TS_NAME
) t1 -- "AS" BEFORE T1 WAS REMOVED

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        TS_NAME          AS "Test Naam2",
        RN_TESTCYCL_ID   AS "Test Case ID",
        COUNT(*) AS "Totaal1"
    FROM
        RUN,
        TEST
    WHERE
        RN_TESTCYCL_ID IN (
            8492,
            8493,
            8494,
            8495,
            8496,
            8497,
            8498,
            8499,
            8500,
            8502
        )
        AND RN_TEST_ID = TS_TEST_ID
            AND RN_EXECUTION_DATE > TO_DATE('2019/07/09 00:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')    /*calculate only after 8th of july (stable tests) */
    GROUP BY
        RN_TESTCYCL_ID,
        RN_TEST_ID,
        TS_NAME,
        TEST.TS_TEST_ID
    ORDER BY
        TS_NAME
) T2 ON (T1."Test Naam1" = T2."Test Naam2")) -- "AS" BEFORE T2 WAS REMOVED
-- where    "Test Naam1" = "Test Naam2" -- THIS IS "ON" CONDITION OF JOIN. SO REMOVED "WHERE CLAUSE"
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks you so much. That worked for me (had to change something to avoid ambigously defined columns to SELECT
    t1."Test Naam1",
    t1."Execution Status",
    t1."Test Case ID",
    t1."Totaal2",
    t2."Totaal1").